# Change marker color Android GoogleMaps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, colors

I'm trying to change the color of the marker.

I can do it using:

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(float hue)
```

But I have problems to convert my RGB color to hue color, I found a solution http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.htm and I set it in a function:

```
public static float rgbToHue(float r, float g, float b) {

    r = r/255;
    g = g/255;
    b = b/255;

    float max = Math.max(r,g);
    max = Math.max(max, b);
    float min = Math.min(r,g);
    min = Math.min(min, b);

    float delta = max - min;

    float hue = 0;

    if(max == r){
        System.out.println("r");
        hue = 60 * ((g-b)/delta);
    }
    else if (max == g) {
        System.out.println("g");
        hue = 60 * (((b-r)/delta)+2);
    }
    else if (max == b) {
        System.out.println("b");
        hue = 60 * (((r-g)/delta)+4);
    }

    System.out.println(hue);
    System.out.println("--");
    return hue;

}
```

But the result didn't really works and I have some negative result (not between 0 and 360)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use any value from RGB and map that to just hue. In [HSL / HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) there are two other values, which are currently hardcoded somewhere in the internals of the library to be full saturation / half of the lightness and full value.

You are welcome to post a feature request for that on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2).

I'd also suggest simply not using default `Marker` icons and create your own instead.

Comment: Yes I think this is the best way

Answer (score 0):

Changing Marker Color

By default map marker color will be RED. Google maps provides some set of predefined colored icons for the marker.

// ROSE color icon

> ```
>  marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
> ```

// GREEN color icon

> ```
>  marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
> ```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Yes I know but I'd like to get my color from rgb and not a defined color